# Passing value to javascript from asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function abc()
{
    var id = document.getElementById('123');
    var caption= <%=MyProperty %>;
}
</script>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.RegisterStartupScript(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),"<script language = 'javascript'>abc();</script>");
}

protected int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

i need to pass string value to javascript, with int this codes works fine.

```
protected string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return "123";
    }
}
```

when i tried to pass string this code does't works.

Comment: remove incorrect spaces in `"<script language = 'javascript'>abc();</script>"`. This should be `"<script language='javascript' type="text/javascript">abc();</script>"`. You can also use this overload to automatically generate the script block: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScriptBlock(typeofyourpage, "somekey", "abc();", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to pass a String you have to specify the delimiters " or '

```
var caption= "<%=MyProperty %>";
```

or

```
var caption= '<%=MyProperty %>';
```

without them the javascript interprets the string value of MyProperty  as the name of a Javascript variable.

Comment: Steve B : I understand that @user1820649 wants to try protected string MyProperty; I may not have fully understood the purpose of the application.

Comment: I get CS0103: The name 'MyProperty' does not exist in the current context